# Javascript - Editing image every minute, updating image

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a `Generator` where a user can insert their Battlenet Name (**name**) and have it output their Emblem (**data.characters[2].embemBackground**) plus their light level (**data.characters[0].light**) on the image too.

Then, I want the user to be able to use an image link, such as: http://www.test.com/image.png

And have it get updated automatically with the stats from the API, so it overwrites the image without changing the URL.

Result:

[image: Result]

I used html2canvas capture to get the image itself from (**#character2img**)

I do realize this is probably not the best way to approach this.

Code:

```
const { Client } = require('destiny2');
const client = new Client('apiKey');
const html2canvas = require('html2canvas');

window.memberName = function(){
    var pName = document.getElementById("pageheader");
    var pLl = document.getElementById('LightLevel');
    var pLl2 = document.getElementById('LightLevel2');
    var pLl3 = document.getElementById('LightLevel3');
    var gT = document.getElementById('Guardian');
    var gT2 = document.getElementById('Guardian2');
    var gT3 = document.getElementById('Guardian3');
    var divI = document.getElementById('character1img');
    var name = document.getElementById('search').value;

    client.getProfile(name, '4')
    .then(data => console.log(data));

    client.getProfile(name, '4').then(data => {
        pName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${data.profile.displayName}`));

// Character 1
    // Emblem Image
        var elem = document.createElement("img");
        elem.src = `http://bungie.net${data.characters[0].embemBackground}`;
        var image = document.getElementById('character1img').appendChild(elem);
    // Light Level
        pLl.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`♦ ${data.characters[0].light}`));
// Character 2
    // Emblem Image
        var elem = document.createElement("img");
        elem.src = `http://bungie.net${data.characters[1].embemBackground}`;
        var image2 = document.getElementById('character2img').appendChild(elem);
    // Light Level
        pLl2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`♦ ${data.characters[1].light}`));
// Character 3
    // Emblem Image
        var elem = document.createElement("img");
        elem.src = `http://bungie.net${data.characters[2].embemBackground}`;
        var image2 = document.getElementById('character3img').appendChild(elem);
    // Light Level
        pLl3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`♦ ${data.characters[2].light}`));
      });

}

window.screenshot = function(){
    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#character1img"), {allowTaint : true}).then(canvas => {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas)
    });
}

window.screenshot2 = function(){
    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#character2img"), {allowTaint : true}).then(canvas => {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas)
    });
}

window.screenshot3 = function(){
    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#character3img"), {allowTaint : true}).then(canvas => {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas)
    });
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific question here?

Comment: Not sure if it's specific, I am just unsure how to tackle this problem.

Comment: Question was: How do I get an image to be generated that updates every, say, 15 minutes to update the lightlevel? Having it be one URL that a user can use, and that only the image gets changed.